# Django form doesn't show input field on browser

Tags: python, django, django-forms

In browser the form only shows submit and reset button 
No errors are prompted on browser

forms.py

```
from django import forms
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    title = forms.CharField()
    text  = forms.CharField(widget = forms.Textarea)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from poll.forms import ContactForm

def contact(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    contact_form = ContactForm(request.POST or None)
    if contact_form.is_valid():
        success = True
        email = contact_form.cleaned_data['email']
        title = contact_form.cleaned_data['title']
        text = contact_form.cleaned_data['text']
else :
    contact_form = ContactForm()

ctx = {'contact_form':contact_form}

return render_to_response('poll/contact.html', ctx )
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^contact/$', views.contact,name = 'contact_form')
```

poll/templates/poll/contact.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Contact us</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Contact us</h1>
<form action="." method="POST">
{{ contact_form.as_p }}

<p><input type="submit" value="Submit"></p> 
<p><input type="reset" value="reset"></p>
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

I call this contact form from  detail.html and url of this form is poll/templates/poll/detail.html

```
<h1>{{ poll.question }}</h1>

{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}
<a href = "{% url 'poll:contact_form' %}">click me</a>
<form action="{% url 'poll:vote' poll.id %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{% for choice in poll.choice_set.all %}
    <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}" />
    <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text }}</label><br />
{% endfor %}
<input type="submit" value="Vote" />
</form>
```

please please please help me . i have tried a lot but could not solve it . thanks in advance

Comment: I see that you are not seeing any errors on your browser.  But, what about your command line interface through which django is started up? Do you see any message (info, verbose, error) in the CLI?

Comment: @Neeraj T No errors are there as well . It shows status 200 i.e OK

Comment: Code works as expected. Are you rendering the correct template? You seem to be rendering `polls/contact.html` but the path seems to be `polls/template/contact.html`.

Comment: Good catch, limelights. @sagar I second him.

Comment: @limelights my mistake while typing the url of contact.html . now i corrected the path. In that url first "poll" is my app

Comment: Is your identation correct? because the if statements are in the same level with your view function.

Comment: @petkostas Indentation is okay . Otherwise django would have flashed the error . right ?

Comment: @sagar yes it should, also you say form.py but you import from forms.py again I believe this is just a mistake transfering the code to stackoverflow?

Comment: any one has any solution for this ?

Comment: please help me to solve it

Comment: @Sagar I know it's been years since you had the problem, but do you by any chance remember the solution?

Comment: @Keselme. I have done the installation again and it did work